# Иерархия рубрик wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток. В wordpress есть файл category.php, который отвечает за вывод категорий, но что делать, если необходимо вывести множество подкатегорий с углублением в каждую? Приведу пример:
Есть главная страница, на которой выведен список категорий, открыв одну из них - мы попадаем на страницу со списком подкатегорий родительской, открыв подкатегорию - попадем на страницу с очередным списком подкатегорий и т.д. Схематически это выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: делаешь категории и на каждой странице выводишь список "псевдокатегорий", которые ведут на нужные тебе линки

Comment: Если бы делал сайт для себя - примерно так и решил бы эту проблему, но клиент планирует добавлять категории, поэтому необходим вариант с автоматическим выводом.

Comment: @waspmax1 - можешь подсказать как ты решил свой вопрос с выводом такой иерархии пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Вы описали по сути структуру каталога.
Я бы воспользовался функцией [get_category_parents()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_category_parents) в шаблоне **category.php**.

На всякий случай не забудьте проверить на [is_category()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/is_category).

UPD: думаю, для проверки наличия дочерних категорий понадобится [get_category()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_category), точнее, возвращаемый параметр **parent**.

Правда, вся эта конструкция влечёт за собой кучу циклов и запросов.

Можно посмотреть в сторону WooCommerce с отключенной корзиной, как вариант.

**UPD**: Согласен с комментаторам, набросал небольшой кусок как можно реализовать.

```
<?php

            $currentCategory = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false); //получаем текущую категорию
            $currentCategoryID = $currentCategory->term_id; //получаем ID текущей категории             

            //Получаем список всех "детей" по типу таксономии и ID
            $termID = $currentCategoryID;
            $taxonomyName = "category";
            $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

            //Выводим списком с ссылками
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($termchildren as $child) 
            {
                //получаем дочернюю категорию
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName);

                //проверяем, принадлежит ли категория к выбранному родителю, т.к. get_term_children возращает всех детей независимо от их вложенности
                if($term->parent==$termID)
                {
                    //если принадлежит - выводим
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        ?>
```

Comment: Тоже думал про woocommerce, у нее же присутствует вложенность категорий?

Comment: Вложенность поддерживается точно, точные функции для вывода не скажу.

Comment: А ты думаешь  woocommerce как-то иначе сделан?

Comment: Конечно нет, ему codex не позволит :), я имею ввиду что по woocommerce надо поднимать документацию и смотреть через что всё работает: функции/хуки.

Comment: @D.Lomov, по-моему, вы решаете противоположную задачу - хотите вывести всех предков текущей категории, а не все подкатегории.

Comment: поддержку @Ponio. Задача в определении потомков, а не предков

Answer (score 1):

Файл `category.php`:

```
// получаем информацию о запрашиваемом объекте, у нас это категория:
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
// следующая строчка полезна при работе с произвольными таксономиями:
// $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy; // в нашем случае 'category'
// получаем дочерние категории:
$child_cats = get_categories(array(
  'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'child_of' => $queried_object->term_id
));
if(count($child_cats)){  
  // выводим ссылки на дочерние категории:
  foreach ($child_cats as $key => $cat) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);?>">
      <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
    </a><?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: В случае с файлом `category.php` строка `$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;` избыточна, имхо

Comment: @alenkins, так и есть, внесла пояснение в ответ.